# Swift Retrieving Data Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve string key which I have saved it in the object

[image]

```
  func retrieveData() {
    let refAll = Database.database().reference().child("Playground")
    refAll.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        if let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            var playgroundSnapshot = snapshotValue
            let playgroundKeys = Array(playgroundSnapshot.keys)
            self.playgroundArray.removeAll()
            for key in playgroundKeys  {
                guard
                    let value = playgroundSnapshot[key] as? [String : Any]
                    else {
                        continue
                }
                let title = value["title"] as! String
                let city = value["city"] as! String
                let location = value["location"] as! String
                let price = value["price"] as! String

                let playground = Playground(title: title, price: price, location: location, city: city, availblePlayground: true)
                self.playgroundArray.append(playground)
            }
            self.tabeView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

and in the playgroundArray there is key for each object

```
 keySelected = playgroundArray[indexPath.row].key
```

but I don't know why keySelected is nil even tho playgroundArray has objects

Answer (score 0):

playgroundArray does not contain "key" . You have to set the **Playground Struct.** Add `var key:String?` and also add this to `init()` func.

```
let playground = Playground(title: title, price: price, location: location, city: city, availblePlayground: true)
```

**to**

```
let playground = Playground(title: title, price: price, location: location, city: city, availblePlayground: true, key: key)


self.playgroundArray.append(playground)
```

Comment: I've tried it, and the array is empty. it seems like the view controller loads everything (gives me empty array) --> loads retrieveData() --> tableView. is there a way to make retrieveData() the first priority?

Comment: can you share  " print(snapshot) " output?